# Finding value with earliest year in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, numbers, find

I'm writing a function where I need to search through a dictionary and return the keys and part of the value(s) that include the earliest year and if there is more then one return them as a list of tuples.

Example Dictionary:

```
{
        'V':[("Self-Portrait",1500,20.0,30.0,"oil paint","Italy")],
        'B':[("Self-Portrait",1500,20.0,20.0,"oil paint","Italy")],
        'K':[("Self-Portrait-1",1500,10.0,20.0,"oil paint","Netherlands"),("Self-Portrait-2",1510,10.0,20.0,"oil paint","Netherlands"),("Self-Portrait-3",1505,10.0,20.0,"oil paint","USA")],
        'M':[("Self-Portrait-1",1800,20.0,15.0,"oil paint","USA"),("Self-Portrait-2",1801,10.0,30.0,"oil paint","France")]
        }
```

From this dictionary if my function was searching for the earliest year(s) it would return

```
earliest_year(dictionary1())

[('B', 'Self-Portrait'), ('K', 'SelfPortrait-1'),
('V', 'Self-Portrait')]
```

Three of the years "1500" were the same (and the earliest) so it returned a list of those three keys were the 1st element of the value and ignored the one with "1800". I've started working on code for this but I'm not sure how to check for the earliest year and get the error "Unexpected EOF" since I'm not asking the function to do anything yet. Any help would be appreciated

```
def earliest_year(dictionary):   
 matches = []
 if not dictionary:
    return None
 for key in dictionary:
    for record in dictionary[key]:
```

Comment: Why nah? You can't disembowel a `for` loop like so, you could at least give it a `pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It first finds the minimum year and then finds all the pairs that have this minimum year.

```
def earliest_year(dictionary):
    matches = []
    min_year = min(tpl[1] for lst in dictionary.values() for tpl in lst)
    for key, lst in dictionary.items():
        for tpl in lst:
            if tpl[1] == min_year:
                matches.append((key, tpl[0]))
    return matches
```

Comment: Thanks could you give example output for this? I'm testing it with a dictionary and it seems to just be returning an empty list

Comment: Sorry, return statement was missing. Should work now.

Comment: I'm getting a error min() arg is an empty sequence in one of the cases do you know what could be causing that? Its weird because the function seems to work correctly

Comment: I tested and it seems to give the error when the dictionary is empty

Comment: How would you fix that?

Comment: I tried adding  if not dictionary:
        return None which worked in another function but that doesnt work. I'll play around with it I just dont want there to be a ValueError in those instances where the dictionary is empty and instead maybe return None

Comment: I'm going to try adding this into a try/except and do except valueerror return none that should work

Comment: If you add `if not dictionary: return None` at the beginning of the function it should work. Are you sure the dictionary is really empty? Maybe any of the lists is empty? It's good to check that too.

Comment: When I test it myself with dictionary = {} it gives me the Value error so I believe it has to do with when the dict is empty. This answer was helpful though I should be able to figure out this small issue

Comment: It ended up working with if not dictionary: return None it must have had to do with my spacing before

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with a conditional list comprehension:

```
d = {
  'B': [('Self-Portrait', 1500, 20.0, 20.0, 'oil paint', 'Italy')],
  'K': [('Self-Portrait-1', 1500, 10.0, 20.0, 'oil paint', 'Netherlands'),
        ('Self-Portrait-2', 1510, 10.0, 20.0, 'oil paint', 'Netherlands'),
        ('Self-Portrait-3', 1505, 10.0, 20.0, 'oil paint', 'USA')],
  'M': [('Self-Portrait-1', 1800, 20.0, 15.0, 'oil paint', 'USA'),
        ('Self-Portrait-2', 1801, 10.0, 30.0, 'oil paint', 'France')],
  'V': [('Self-Portrait', 1500, 20.0, 30.0, 'oil paint', 'Italy')]}
}

>>> {key: [v for v in vals if v[1] == min(v_[1] for v_ in vals)] 
     for key, vals in d.items()}
{'B': [('Self-Portrait', 1500, 20.0, 20.0, 'oil paint', 'Italy')],
 'K': [('Self-Portrait-1', 1500, 10.0, 20.0, 'oil paint', 'Netherlands')],
 'M': [('Self-Portrait-1', 1800, 20.0, 15.0, 'oil paint', 'USA')],
 'V': [('Self-Portrait', 1500, 20.0, 30.0, 'oil paint', 'Italy')]}
```